# Qt app in Mavericks broken filechooser

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, osx-mavericks

My app has a function where the user simply gets files from his computer, seams quite common.
This is the way I do this in c++ in Qt5 :

```
QStringList fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(0,"Choose File(s)",QDir::homePath());
```

This has always worked. but on Osx.9 Mavericks it doesn't.. it simply crashes.. (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Is anybody aware of something changed in Maverick? It tried on a completely different machine to see if it's only on one machine and it crashes too.